# Multiple posts on click to submit form using jquery dialog and asp mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am using the following form :

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveItem", "ItemsController", null, new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "onFormSubmit" }, new { id = "itemSaveForm" }))
{ // form fields below

}
```

and the fallowing javascript code to manage this :

```
  function onFormSubmit(content) {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
        $("#form-data").html(""); //empty form

        $.post('@Url.Action("GetItemRow", "ItemsController")', { id: id, adm:true }, function (data) {
           // update logic.. ignore
            }

        });
    }
```

and this is the jquery dialog script witch i use to submit :

```
 $(function () {
        $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 255,
            width: 420,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Add": function () {
                    var bValid = true;
                    $("#itemSaveForm").submit();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {

            }
        });
    });
```

and every time i press the Add button from the dialog box... i get multiple submissions. Any ideeas why?

Comment: my bad, i should have searched b4 posting the answer, anyhow deleted it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the following line is the origin of your problems:

```
$("#itemSaveForm").submit();
```

How about using a normal HTML form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveItem", "Items", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "itemSaveForm" }))   
{
    ...
}
```

and then configure the `Add` button on your dialog like this:

```
'Add': function () {
    var bValid = true;
    var form = $('#itemSaveForm');
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: onFormSubmit
    });
}
```

Comment: If i use your method the form get submited even tho i have validation errors. Eny ideea how i can trigger the validation manualy? So i can submit only if its valid?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either `return false;` or `e.preventDefault();` or the JS code will handle the submit and after that the form is submitted.

`return false;`

does both `.preventDefault();` and `.stopPropgation()`.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/